# CSV file - RStudio does not recognize values in the columns [pcr package used]

Tags: r, rstudio

I work on the data from qPCR experiment. The dataset I want to use was produced in Excel - table of 2 columns, 90 rows, all values are numeric (decimal place - period). The file was saved as CSV and opened in RStudio as such. For my work, I use pcr package (tidyverse and dplyr also loaded in).
However, upon using one of the commands in this package, I get an error.

Checked the length of the columns, one is shown as 2 (it should not be, as there are 10 variables, each of them is repeated 9 times). The other one is not recognized

```r
> View(MIR393a_R)
> group_var <- rep(c("Col-0 B", "Col-0 A", "Kyoto B", "Kyoto A", "Kb-0 B", "Kb-0 A", "Db-1 B", "Db-1 A", "Durh-1 B", "Durh-1 A"), each = 9)
> pcr_analyze(MIR393a_R, group_var = group_var, reference_gene ='Reference', reference_group = 'MIR393a', method = 'delta_delta_ct', plot = FALSE)
```

What should be there:
Calculated values and errors of double delta (plot is optional if plot = TRUE)
What I obtained:

```
Error: Column `MIR393a` must be length 10 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
3: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
4: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
5: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
6: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
7: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
8: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
9: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
10: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: What is returned when you run `str(MIR393a_R)?`

Comment: `
> str(MIR393a)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 90 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ MIR393a  : num  34.7 34.8 34.1 34.5 34.4 ...
 $ Reference: num  28 28.3 27.9 26.7 26.8 ...
`

Comment: I am new to using R and RStudio with the real data, so I may have made a few mistakes. Both MIR393a and Reference are seen as characters (they are the headlines of the resepctive columns). Not sure how to make the whole column count.

Comment: They should be fine as characters; what about `str(MIR393a)`?

Comment: Yields "object not found"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the pcr package you are using, but is it possible you should set 
reference_group = 'MIR393a_R'
 not 'MIR393a' in the pcr_analyze line?

Comment: MIR393_a already goes as a data frame, reference_group should be Ct values for target gene according to the package pdf manual

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems I have finally figured it out oon my own.

For reference_group in pcr_analyze, a group from previously defined group_var should be selected, not the entire column.

```
pcr_analyze(MIR, group_var = gvar, reference_gene = 'Reference', reference_group ='Col-0 B', method = 'delta_delta_ct')
```

where MIR - is the data frame, gvar <- rep(c('name1', 'name2',...), each = 9), reference_gene = 'Ref' (previously assigned as Ref <- MIR$ReferenceGene), reference_group = 'name1', for example

The correct formula gave the output

```
   group    gene    normalized calibrated relative_expression error  lower upper
   <chr>    <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>               <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1 Col-0 A  MIR393a      11.3      4.44                0.0461 1.53  0.0160 0.133
 2 Col-0 B  MIR393a       6.90     0                   1      0.775 0.584  1.71 
 3 Db-1 A   MIR393a       8.84     1.94                0.260  1.85  0.0723 0.936
 4 Db-1 B   MIR393a       8.34     1.45                0.366  1.33  0.146  0.922
 5 Durh-1 A MIR393a       7.72     0.826               0.564  2.89  0.0758 4.19 
 6 Durh-1 B MIR393a       6.96     0.0601              0.959  1.40  0.363  2.54 
 7 Kb-0 A   MIR393a      11.3      4.42                0.0467 1.69  0.0145 0.151
 8 Kb-0 B   MIR393a       8.00     1.11                0.465  2.20  0.101  2.13 
 9 Kyoto A  MIR393a       9.70     2.80                0.143  1.64  0.0459 0.448
10 Kyoto B  MIR393a       9.74     2.84                0.140  1.58  0.0469 0.416
```

Case is solved :)